# Rails does not update the fingerprint for some assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets, fingerprint

I notice there is a weird thing going on in rails 4.2.0. I am using the default dev environment. When I change some of my JS files, the fingerprint does not change and it keeps serving the old file. The weird thing is that this does not happen to all my JS/CSS files. I tried rebooting my machine and restarting rails server. None of them worked. Renaming the file works, but when I rename it back to the old one, it starts serving the old version again. Anyone has an idea why?

Comment: I've been struggling with this for days.

Comment: Oh sorry, I haven't been active for sometime.  Another way to solve this might be removing the tmp folder as I have found out.

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this that doesn't involve every user to reset their browser cache themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to set `config.serve_static_files = false` in your config/environments/development.rb and to reset your browser cache.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if we have the same situation, but hopefully this helps.

[Reference](https://bibwild.wordpress.com/2014/10/02/non-digested-asset-names-in-rails-4-your-options/)

I was using a custom application-all.scss instead of the normal application.scss stylesheet in which application-all.scss used to be part of `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile`.

I renamed application-all.scss into the digested-name application.scss, and updated related code.

After that, it worked now for me.

Comment: You renamed what to what?

Comment: I renamed application-all.scss into application.scss, and then removed application-all.scss from Rails.application.config.assets.precompile :)